# Is this vertical crack/split in stud significant?

Tags: wood, studs, crack, frame

Stud is in the exterior wall of my garage. I am looking to hang something fairly heavy (*30-40lbs*) using lag bolts on this stud.

I am curious if the vertical cracks would be an issue or if they are fairly normal sized and insignificant.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rTlfN.jpg
[image]

Comment: I can't load imgur at work, but I suspect a lag bolt is going to be overkill for 30-40 pounds. If it's going into a stud, a 10d or larger nail should be fine, assuming whatever you're hanging isn't going to have dynamic forces applied.

Comment: Lag bolt might be overkill for sure, it’s just what came with the product I will be hanging and recommended for installation into a stud. Uploaded one of the three photos directly to give you (or anyone else who can’t access Imgur) a look at the vertical cracks moving up the stud. Thanks for taking a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That crack looks fine to me. From the image it looks to be mostly superficial... I might drill a pilot hole if the screw is going dead center where the crack is, just to make sure the crack doesn't widen. If you want to err on the safe side, you can get another 2x4 stud and nail it to the side of the existing, cracked stud (*this is called sistering*) with some 10D nails every couple of feet and then attach this item to the new 2x4 stud.

Comment: @AlaskaMan if you're going to edit, please don't introduce errors. Parentheticals don't belong inside their own pair of commas. Likewise, paragraphs don't need to be 3 sentences. Or indented with non-rendered spaces. Edits should improve posts, not make stylistic, personal-preference changes.

Comment: Please break your Wall of words into paragraphs so it easy to read and digest.

Comment: @AlaskaMan 3 sentences is not a wall of words. They've taught 5-7 sentences for a *typical* paragraph in high schools for a couple decades now. Downvoting out of spite over how a post is styled is also not really proper form.

Comment: I put a paragraph break where it separated the first part of you answer  from the second.  Is that not what paragraphs are for?  It does help the reader. There is no law about paragraph size.

Comment: Would you recommend sistering the entire length if I go that route or just the portion showing the cracks/being used to bolt into?

Comment: @Cody Typically sistering is done for the whole length, but given this is in the garage, I understand it might be significantly higher than 8ft (a typical 2x4 length) You don't need to go all 10/14/however-many feet to the top plates, but I would go at least from the bottom plate up to a foot or so past where you want to hang something. And I would toe-nail two nails at the bottom so that it's attached to both the original stud and the bottom plate.

Comment: @Cody The extra rigidity from the longer 2x4 will only help. Since it'd be an extra stud, you can use screws instead of nails, that way you could start with some scrap 2x4s of shorter length if you have some lying around, to see how sturdy it feels to you. If necessary, you can back out the screws easily and put in a longer piece. Given enough screws even a 2ft-long piece might be enough, technically speaking. But I don't know how big the bolt is that you're using, or what you're hanging, etc.

Comment: Ended up putting in a full length sister stud and toe nailed it. Appreciate all of the advice earlier today. Stud definitely feels sturdier than it did before with everything mounted to it. Thanks again!

Comment: Geeze, let it alone and find something constructive to do with your time. Every answer and comment written on this site is riddled with errors of misplaced commas, periods, misspelled words, and poor sentence structure. I say "SO WHAT", we are not back in high school so let it go. I have even been chastized for putting in a what the moderators called a comment into an answer form. If all you can do is complain, find a new HOBBY> my 2 cents

Comment: @Cody If this post helped solve your problem, consider clicking the check mark near the answer score to let future readers know!